# Specific template loaded with php

Tags: php, joomla

I have a joomla component and I want to have a custom template depends on the resolution.

I have `default_list.php` file where I want to include a php code to load a specific template (`default_list_template1.php`) depending on the device resolution.

Can someone give me a clue?

Comment: PHP runs on the server side, so it has no idea what the device resolution is. Code that runs on the client side like JavaScript can get this information and potentially send it back to the server so that on the next request php could leverage it. But instead I would recommend looking into css media queries as an alternative strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no simple way to get screen-resolution with PHP (server-side language), and moreover, resolution may change over time (screen resize), it is much better to start with responsive CSS well explained at [http://learn.shayhowe.com](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/)

If you want to dig on your own, use "responsive website" and "CSS media queries" search phrases.